# SQLFileStream .Write Exception - The Handle is Invalid

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I've got an uploaded file sitting on our App Server which I am then streaming into a MSSQL database using SQLFileStream, writing in 10mb (I've tried increasing/decreasing this) chunks. This works fine for files under and around 500mb but anything larger and I'm getting an error `The Handle is Invalid` on the line `filestream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` when it gets to around 800mb of the file.

I'm presuming that something is timing out somewhere - can anybody point me in the right direction? Method is below

```
protected bool TransferFileToDB(string DocID, string filePath)
{
    bool success = false;

    // Get the file from the Upload Folder
    FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);

    string conStr = GetConnectionString();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

    if (fi.Exists)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer;
            long position = 0;
            int packetSize = 10 * 1000 * 1024; // 10mb chunks 

            // Open the file for reading
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                long length = fs.Length;

                using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    string filePath = GetDocumentPath(DocID);

                    connection.Open();

                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = "Select GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()As TransactionContext";
                    byte[] transactionContext1 = (byte[])sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                    using (SqlFileStream filestream = new SqlFileStream(filePath, transactionContext1, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();

                        while (position < length)
                        {
                            if (position + packetSize > length)
                            {
                                buffer = new byte[length - position];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                buffer = new byte[packetSize];
                            }

                            //Read file
                            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            //Copy to DB Server
                            filestream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            filestream.Flush();

                            Debug.WriteLine("Copied to DB " + position.ToString());

                            position += buffer.Length;

                        }

                        filestream.Close();
                    }

                    transactionScope.Complete();
                }

                fs.Close();

            }

            // Once file has been sent to DB server, delete temp file on the App Server
             fi.Delete();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error in TransferFileToDB" + e.Message + e.InnerException);
            fi.Delete();
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured this one out, so here is the solution just in case anybody comes across it.

TransactionScope appears to have a default time out of 60 seconds, so passing a time value in the constructor solved all my issues

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope
           (TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromHours(1)))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx